# OPL CPLEX If statement usage with boolean

Tags: if-statement, boolean, cplex, opl

I'm a beginner user of CPLEX OPL. Here is my piece of code:

```
forall(e in employee, d in day:1<=d<=19, t in task, p in period)
(x[e][d][p][t]==0)=>(x[e][d+7][p][t]+x[e][d+8][p][t]+x[e][d+9][p][t]==2);
```

where `x[e][d][p][t]` is a boolean decision variable. This is a small part of code. Is it okay to write a code like this structure?

I appreciate if you would help me.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you make sure d+7 is in the days, that s fine.

For instance:

```
range day =1..20;
range task=1..3;
range period=1..20;
range employee=1..10;


dvar boolean x[employee][day][period][task];
subject to
{

forall(e in employee, d in day:1<=d<=19, t in task, p in period:(d+9) in day) 

(x[e][d][p][t]==0)=>(x[e][d+7][p][t]+x[e][d+8][p][t]+x[e][d+9][p][t]==2);

}
```

works fine